# How do I transform a point from one coordinate system to another coordinate system?

Tags: matrix-equations, transformation, change-of-basis, coordinates

I have an application with a robot world frame and a camera frame. It must be noted that the XY frames of both are parallel so I do not necessarily care about the Z component. The problem I am facing is formulating a function that takes camera XY coordinates and transforms them to the robot XY coordinates.

I have a fiducial on the robot that is presented to the camera and it is on the same plane of the calibrated camera XY plane (If the robot moves 3mm in XY the camera will measure this as a 3mm delta). This allows me to know a specific point in space in the world frame and in the camera frame. I know that I must create a table of points so that I can generate the XY vectors of each frame for calculating the translation and rotation but I am struggling to start this equation. I figured brevity here may help me get started here so please let me know if you need additional details, thanks!

Comment: It requires knowing the locations in both frames of at least two points to figure out a transformation between them. From the information you've given, we only know one such point. Is there some mechanical relation between the frames? For instance, is the camera mounted to the robot? Some additional bit of information will be necessary to solve this - more than just one single point.

Comment: The camera is not mounted on the robot, it is affixed overhead. The fiducial is mounted to the robot and can be moved by the robot to multiple points. For example, the robot may move the point to world frame position (100,100) which might equal (10,20) in the camera. Then I can move the robot to say, (110,105) and the camera might read (12, 25) (these are random numbers and I realize the magnitudes may not match). At this point I can know two points that are related between the world and camera frame.